# SQL Variables - MS Access

Tags: sql, variables, ms-access

This is related to an MS Access database.

I know it is possible to define variables in T-SQL but will this work in MS Access and how?

How can I assign values to variables in SQL the same way it is done for the below VBA script?
As you can see, the aim is to provide the user with a description of what went wrong using:

**`strErrorDescription = strErrorDescription & " " & strErrorDescription2 & " " & strErrorDescription3`**

```
    strTableName = "tblStagingGL_SS04"
    strLogTableName = "tblLogGL_SS04"

    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strTableName)
    Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset(strLogTableName)

    rs.MoveFirst

        Do Until rs.EOF

            'Verifies that the GL_Number only contains numbers
            If rs.Fields(2).Value Like "*[!0-9]*" Then
            strErrorDescription = "Error on GL_Number"
            End If

                'Verifies that the Currency is made of 3 numbers only
                If Not rs.Fields(6).Value Like "[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]" Then
                strErrorDescription2 = "Error on Currency"
                End If

           'Verifies that the Rate does not contain letters
           If rs.Fields(10).Value Like "*[A-Z]*" Then
           strErrorDescription3 = "Error on rate"
           End If

        strErrorDescription = strErrorDescription & " " & strErrorDescription2 & " " & strErrorDescription3

                'If an Error has been caught, create a record with the associated information in the Log table
                If strErrorDescription <> "  " Then

                rs2.AddNew
                rs2.Fields(1).Value = rs.Fields(2).Value
                rs2.Fields(2) = rs.Fields(7)
                rs2.Fields(3) = strErrorDescription
                rs2.Update

                End If

            strErrorDescription = ""
            strErrorDescription2 = ""
            strErrorDescription3 = ""

        rs.MoveNext

        Loop
```

Comment: Don't know a lot about MS Access, but you should probably use a stored procedure for this. Also, be aware that `If Not rs.Fields(6).Value Like "[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]" Then` only checks for capitals (depending on your collation).

Comment: There are no stored procedures in MS Access...

Comment: @ProtoVB You can make a pass-through query in Access to execute a stored procedure

Comment: I am not using SQL server here, MS Access only

Comment: If your goal is an Access query, please show us a brief set of sample data and the query output you want based on those data.

Comment: @HansUp How can I add a table to this webpage?

Comment: Add data as text, in rows and columns, and apply formatting with the `{}` incon.  [example here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27913856/77335)

Comment: @HoneyBadger Access is not case sensitive by default. [A-Z] is the same as [a-z]. Case sensitivity requires special coding.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using a function to provide an error message to a user via ErrorHandling is easy to do - you will need to declare the values in an ErrorHandling function, and reference the built in error properties.

For example, this is what a function on any form, report, or in another module could use to reference the errorhandler:

```
Public Function AnyFunctionName() 
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler                   'Initial Error Handling
    'Whatever your function Does goes here

ExitCode:                                      '
    Exit Function                              '
ErrHandler:                                    'The error handler
    ErrorLog Err.Number, Err.Description 
    Resume ExitCode                            'Resume after error handling at exit code to clear memory
End Function
```

And this would then be the errorhandler function:

```
Public Sub ErrorLog(lngErrNum As Long, strErrDesc As String)
    'Purpose:                                           '
On Error GoTo ErrHandler                                'Initial Error Handling
    'Declare                                            '
    Dim strMsg as string
    'Set                                                '
    'Use                                                '
    strMsg = "The following error has occurred:" & vbNewLine
    strMsg = strMsg & "Error # " & lngErrNum & vbNewLine
    strMsg = strMsg & "Description: " & strErrDesc
    MsgBox strMsg, vbOKOnly Or vbExclamation, "Error"

ExitCode:                                               '
    'Clear                                              'clear all variables declared
    Exit Sub                                            '
ErrHandler:                                             'The error handler
    strMsg = "There has been an error with the error handler."
    MsgBox strMsg, vbOKOnly Or vbExclamation, "Error"
    Resume ExitCode                                     'Resume after error handling at exit code to clear memory
End Sub
```

You could of course modify the 'ErrorLog' function to actually record the error to a table, like I have done in the past.  This will allow you to perform an analysis on any occurring errors to watch for patterns, etc.

I know it has been a while since this question was asked, but I hope this helps someone!