# Unable to get Allen Browne's ConcatRelated to work on a simple table

Tags: ms-access, concatenation

I am trying to use the [ConcatRelated function](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) to provide a summary report of the prior day's absences, tardies, and vacations. I have tried several variations and can't seem to get it to work in an Access Query.  My table looks as below:

```
ID A_date    Area        ATV_Shift Associate_Name Absent  Tardy Vacation Reason
-- --------- ----------- --------- -------------- ------  ----- -------- --------------
1  1/11/2015 Asm Kenmore First     Keon Wilson         1                 Sick
2  1/11/2015 Asm Kenmore First     Frank Burns         1                 Doctor
3  1/11/2015 Asm Kenmore Second    Paul Mattocks       1                 FLMA
4  1/11/2015 Decoration  First     Jane Doe            1                 Car Broke Down
5  1/11/2015 Asm Maytag  Second    John Doe            1
```

I need to make a query that displays the previous days data (`Date()-1`). The reasons need to be separated by spaces.  I can get everything else to sum in a query but I am unable to get the reasons to concat. I have tried following the examples but just cant get it to function. I was only able to get it to work using a simple SQL query but that returned lines for each reason not in one cell.

Comment: I attempted to format your sample data legibly.  Please adjust if I mis-aligned any values.  Also please add the output you want to see from your query.

Comment: I just want a summary for the day.   <For A_Date> <Sum Absent> <Sum Tardy> <Sum Vacation> <concat Reason>.  For the A_Date I am looking to use Date()-1 to get the previous day's data.

Comment: There is no *Reason* in the row which has *ID* 5.  Is that Null or an empty string?  How did you want `ConcatRelated()` to handle that one?

Comment: It should be left blank. If no note it can be a blank space or nothing.  By the way thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

I changed your *A_date* values to 1/13/2015 and stored those sample data in a table named *YourTable*.  Using that table, this is the output in Access 2010 from the query below.

```
A_date    SumOfAbsent SumOfTardy SumOfVacation Reasons
--------- ----------- ---------- ------------- -------------------------------
1/13/2015           5                          Car Broke Down Doctor FLMA Sick
```

```sql
SELECT
    y.A_date,
    Sum(y.Absent) AS SumOfAbsent,
    Sum(y.Tardy) AS SumOfTardy,
    Sum(y.Vacation) AS SumOfVacation,
    ConcatRelated(
            'Reason',
            'YourTable',
            'A_date=Date()-1',
            'Reason',
            ' '
        ) AS Reasons
FROM YourTable AS y
WHERE y.A_date = Date()-1
GROUP BY y.A_date;
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  I will try it tonight.  My only frustration with pulling IT duty along with being the Quality Manager is that I do the fun stuff at night.