# How to combine/concat a column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154644/group-by-to-combine-concat-a-column) on Stack Overflow and it is my exact issue. It was solved, but I am using an Access database and apparently some of the functions described in the solution are not available in Access. How can I achieve that result in Access?

I have a table as follows:

```
ID  User  PageURL  
1    Me     ab     
2    Me     cd     
3    You    xy     
4    You    st
```

I want to group by User such that I end up with something like:

```
User  PageURL  
Me    ab, cd     
You   xy, st
```

As you can see, the column PageURL is combined together separated by a comma based on the group by.

Comment: Can you split your table into 3 separate tables? User, Page and UserPage. So you can query user and concatenate the linked page values.

Comment: I guess so..... I hadn't thought of that. Would that make it easier to combine PageURL and group by User?

Comment: Check out `ConcatRelated()`.  There are many Stack Overflow examples ... here is one: [Unable to get Allen Browne's ConcatRelated to work on a simple table](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27913856/77335)