# Microsoft Access. Grouped query with values from a concatenated field

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, concatenation

I have these tables related like this (next image)

[image]

I need to make a query grouped by **IdObjeto** that shows me the fields, **IdObjeto** , **Objeto** and **Comentarios**. Where the field **Comentarios**, has to be a concatenation of its values for the same **IdObjeto**.

That is, the output of the query should be

[image]

I've tried to do it with this code but I think it's not valid for access because it doesn't support XML, i think it.

`SELECT OBJETOS.IdObjeto, OBJETOS.Objeto`
`STUFF(`
`(SELECT '/ '  + COMENTARIOS.Comentario`
`FROM OBJETOS`
`LEFT JOIN COMENTARIOS ON OBJETOS.[IdObjeto] = COMENTARIOS.[IdObjeto]`
`FOR XML PATH('')),`
`1, 2, '') As COMENTARIOS`
`FROM OBJETOS`

You could help me and tell me some way to get that result. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to get Allen Browne's ConcatRelated to work on a simple table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27913856/unable-to-get-allen-brownes-concatrelated-to-work-on-a-simple-table)

Comment: Yes, thanks! It's a similar problem.