# Access 2007 SQL combine Multiple results into one

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I have a problem with writing a query to generate a single string result from multiple records.

Due to the limitations I have in work,  I am using Access 2007 as a back end and Excel 2007 as a front end - data intput/reports with excel userforms that connect to the database. My users don't/can't have access to Access, only Excel and the systems we're working with can't be ran using Excel as the data store.

The report I'm trying to generate needs to turn a result like this:

```
moduleID | departmentID  
115      |  7  
116      |  7  
116      | 23  
117      |  7  
117      | 23
```

Into this:

```
moduleID | departments  
115      | 7  
116      | 7, 23  
117      | 7, 23
```

Because I'm connecting to the database via a connection in VBA I don't seem to be able to use custom functions which seem to be the main solutions out there and I believe that the XML Path solution is not compatible with Access either.

I did come across a solution that used IIF in some way and has a line like this in the query:

```
 IIF(ISNULL(departments), departmentID, departments & ', ' & departmentID)
```

but I'm having trouble adapting it.

So far I've got this query which gives a COUNT of the departments:

```
SELECT
 moduleID,
 COUNT(departmentID) AS departments
 FROM (
  SELECT 
   forecastingModules.moduleID, Forecasting.departmentID
  FROM
   Forecasting
   LEFT JOIN forecastingModules 
   ON Forecasting.editID = forecastingModules.editID
  GROUP BY
   forecastingModules.moduleID, Forecasting.departmentID
 )
GROUP BY
 moduleID;
```

Thanks for any help you can give to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks @hoangnh, I had seen that but it doesn't quite apply to my problem as it can be any number of departments.

Comment: Maybe a vba solution (in Excel) ?

Comment: that's my last resort as I currently use a set of tools I developed to turn record sets into interactive reports built from controls  and a recordset. I haven't yet set them up for external (to a SQL query) results.

Comment: Common topic. Requires VBA. Does this answer your question? [Unable to get Allen Browne's ConcatRelated to work on a simple table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27913856/unable-to-get-allen-brownes-concatrelated-to-work-on-a-simple-table)

Comment: Why can't users use Access Runtime? It is free.

Comment: I work for an old and large - 5000ish staff - public company in the UK... let's just say the IT department is a little hidebound? Plus a few other reasons to complicated to go into here.