# MS Acces query to populate cell with column header text where that column's value = "Yes"

Tags: ms-access

I have a table that looks like this:

| Patient Name | Injury A | Injury B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Yes | Yes |
| Mary | Yes | No |

I'd like to write a query that populates a column, concatenating the Injury header text, separated by commas, where there is a "Yes" in the one of the Injury columns, as shown below.

| Patient Name | Injury A | Injury B | All Injuries |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Yes | Yes | Injury A, Injury B |
| Mary | Yes | No | Injury A |

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are InjuryA and InjuryB text type fields?

Comment: Yes, they are text type fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use IIf() expression.

```
SELECT Table1.PatientName, Table1.InjuryA, Table1.InjuryB, 
IIf([InjuryA]="Yes","InjuryA",Null) & IIf([InjuryA]="Yes" And [InjuryB]="Yes",", ",Null) & IIf([InjuryB]="Yes","InjuryB",Null) AS AllInjuries
FROM Table1;
```

Comment: If I add an additional Injury, InjuryC, so that the query reads like this: SELECT Table1.PatientName, Table1.InjuryA, Table1.InjuryB, 
IIf([InjuryA]="Yes","InjuryA",Null) & IIf([InjuryA]="Yes" And [InjuryB]="Yes" And [InjuryC] = "Yes" ,", ",Null) & IIf([InjuryB]="Yes","InjuryB",Null) & IIf([InjuryC]="Yes","InjuryC"AS AllInjuries 
FROM Table1;  the output column values are no longer comma separated. Any ideas?

Comment: Write a VBA custom function. Your data structure is not normalized. If you want to allow any number of injuries for each patient, then normalize - then, again, use VBA https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27913856/unable-to-get-allen-brownes-concatrelated-to-work-on-a-simple-table