# MS Access - create and populate column containing concatenated text separated by commas with no repeating values

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables in MS Access, one with foods and associated companies:

| FoodID | Food | Company |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | Vino Farms |
| 2 | Orange | Citrus Co. |
| 3 | Banana | Vino Farms |

and one with information about whether someone ate the food

| ClientID | ClientName | Apple | Orange | Banana |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob | Yes | No | Yes |
| 2 | Tyler | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| 3 | Joe | No | No | No |

I'd like to write a query that creates a column populated by the company that makes the foods someone reported eating, separated by commas. If someone reports eating a more than one food made by the same company, I only want the company's name listed once:

| ClientID | ClientName | AssociatedCompanies |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob | Vino Farms |
| 2 | Tyler | Vino Farms, Citrus Co. |
| 3 | Joe |  |

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Start by _normalising_ your tables. The Client table isn't; neither is the Food table, as Company (Supplier) should be a separate table. When done, you'll find your task easily solved.

Comment: As suggested by comment to your other question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69337883/ms-acces-query-to-populate-cell-with-column-header-text-where-that-columns-valu/69338494#69338494), normalize data structure. Then the same VBA procedure can be used. Normalization means there would only be records when a client ate a food.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by Gustav, start by normalizing your "ate food" Table. It should look like:

```
1 Bob   Apple
1 Bob   Banana
2 Tyler Apple
2 Tyler Orange
2 Tyler Banana
```

You then get what you want with the following Query:

```
-- Group companies into one field, separated with commas
SELECT ClientID, ClientName, RemoveCommas(Company1 & ", " & Company2 & ", " ... & CompanyN)
FROM
(  -- Convert rows (records) into columns (fields) 
   SELECT ClientID, ClientName
   , Max(Iif(Company="Vino Farms", "Vino Farms", Null)) AS Company1
   , Max(Iif(Company="Citrus Co.", "Citrus Co.", Null)) AS Company2
   , ...
   , Max(Iif(Company="Last_company", "Last_company", Null)) AS CompanyN
   FROM 
      (-- Replace food by its manufacturing company
       SELECT DISTINCT ClientID, ClientName, Company
       FROM
          Table_ate_food_normalized AS Ate
       INNER JOIN
          Table_food AS Comp
       ON Ate.Food = Comp.Food
      )
   GROUP BY ClientID, ClientName 
)
```

Notice the following relevant points:

1. This will only work, as you notice, for a **fixed number** of companies with **names hardcoded in the Query**. This is a **very severe** limitation. If these restrictions are not satisfied, I suggest that you use a TRANSFORM Query, but, you would not get the companies as a single text field with values separated by commas, and you would rather get them as a variable number of fields, each field having a Yes/No value (similar to your current "ate food" table).
2. I am assuming that the values of "food" and "Company" are each a candidate key in its Table. Otherwise, use the corresponding ID fields, and get the actual values using an inner join.
3. If you want to understand better the part of converting rows into columns, you may check the Query "K_rows_into_columns_1" from the database of examples dowloadable from [LightningGuide.net](https://LightningGuide.net).
4. You have to code the user defined VBA function "RemoveCommas()" to remove unncessary commas from the string containing the listing of companies. If unncessesary commas do not bother you, then you can do the Query without coding this functions.
5. If you want to code the TRANSFORM alternative that I suggested above, you may check the Query "K_rows_into_columns_2" from the database of examples dowloadable from [LightningGuide.net](https://LightningGuide.net).